# Show a div when radio button is checked and add required attribute to only the input fields

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show a DIV by checking a radio button and when that DIV is visible then REQUIRED attribute will be added to its INPUT fields using jquery, But if the radio button is unchecked and the DIV is hidden, the REQUIRED attribute is also removed. BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET IT DONE

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name=post-format]').on('click init-post-format', function() {
    $('#private-box').toggle($('#private_office').prop('checked'));
  }).trigger('init-post-format');

  $('input[name=post-format]').on('click init-post-format', function() {
    $('#public-box').toggle($('#public_office').prop('checked'));
  }).trigger('init-post-format');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-top">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="btn btn-warning">
    <input type="radio" name="acc-type" value="private_office" id="private_office"> Private Office
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-warning">
    <input type="radio" name="acc-type" value="public_office" id="public_office"> Public Office
    </label>
  </div>


  <div id="private-box">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">Ministry</label>
      <input type="text" id="ministry" name="ministry" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">Agency </label>
      <input type="text" id="agency" name="agency" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="public-box">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">State/ Region</label>
      <input type="text" id="ministry_region" name="ministry_region" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">District</label>
      <input type="text" id="ministry_district" name="ministry_district" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EbbySVHesse which DIV do you want to show or hide?

Comment: @alfredo, I have 2 DIVs <div id="private-box"> and <div id="public-box">, the 2 radio button handles the 2 DIVs

Comment: @alfredo, when radio button: #private-office is checked it should SHOW the DIV #private-box, same for the other radio button.

Comment: The code in the answer by htr5 shows one way to do it. To set the attribute in jquery you can do something like $('#agency').prop('required', true); Good luck!

Comment: @alfredo, the REQUIRED attribute is added to the input field when the DIV is active.

Comment: Since it looks like @htr5 is not going to complete his answer I gave you another answer down below.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS to hide both divs by default:

```
#private-box, #public-box {
    display: none;
}
```

I assume you only want one div showing at a time so add the following to each input radio button:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('private-box').style.display='block';document.getElementById('public-box').style.display='none'"
```

Then reverse the block/none display properties for each button.

Result:

```css
#private-box, #public-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-top">
<div class="form-group">       

<label class="btn btn-warning">
<input type="radio" onchange="document.getElementById('private-box').style.display='block';document.getElementById('public-box').style.display='none'" name="acc-type" value="private_office" id="private_office"> Private Office
</label>

<label class="btn btn-warning">
<input type="radio" onchange="document.getElementById('public-box').style.display='block';document.getElementById('private-box').style.display='none'" name="acc-type" value="public_office" id="public_office"> Public Office
</label>
</div>


<div id="private-box">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="ministry">Ministry</label>
<input type="text" id="ministry" name="ministry" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="ministry">Agency </label>
<input type="text" id="agency" name="agency" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>

<div id="public-box">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="ministry">State/ Region</label>
<input type="text" id="ministry_region" name="ministry_region" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="ministry">District</label>
<input type="text" id="ministry_district" name="ministry_district" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Play with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/j75kq4xp/

Comment: Almost there. Also show him how to set the required attribute for the inputs that are showing and hide them when they are not showing.

Comment: @htr5, Thank you for your answer it worked fine for SHOW and HIDE radios

Comment: @alfredo, yes, SHOW / HIDE div is ok now how do i add required to the input field of only the ACTIVE div

Comment: Do something like $('#agency').prop('required', true);  to show the agency input and $('#agency').prop('required', false) to hide it. I think it's best to keep your javascript separate from your HTML, so it's best not to have it in the input but to keep it separate like you have in your question. I don't want to take the credit off @hrt5 so I'll let him complete the answer for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS to start with the DIVS hidden:

```
#private-box, #public-box {
    display: none;
}
```

Use this JQuery code to create the events and set/remove the "required" property on the input fields.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#private_office').on('click', function() {
            $('#private-box').css('display', 'block');
            $('#private-box').prop('required', true); 
            $('#ministry').prop('required', true);          
            $('#agency').prop('required', true);    

            $('#public-box').css('display', 'none');   
            $('#public-box').prop('required', false); 
            $('#ministry_region').prop('required', false);          
            $('#ministry_district').prop('required', false);    
        });

        $('#public_office').on('click', function() {
            $('#private-box').css('display', 'none');
            $('#private-box').prop('required', false);
            $('#ministry').prop('required', false);         
            $('#agency').prop('required', false);   

            $('#public-box').css('display', 'block');    
            $('#public-box').prop('required', true);    
            $('#ministry_region').prop('required', true);           
            $('#ministry_district').prop('required', true); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: REQUIRED is not working cos form is still submitted without any info in the input field and when you preview code, there is no required attribute added to the ACTIVE DIV.

Comment: Sorry, I had some typos and missed some code. See if that works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*THIS IS THE CODE I USE TO SHOW AND HIDE THE DIV BUT WANTS A BETTER AND SIMPLE WAY OF DOING IT */
var keys = {
  'private_office': '#private-box',
  'public_office': '#public-box'
}
$('input[name=acc-type]').on('click', function() {
  that = $(this)
  $('input[name=acc-type]').each(function() {
    if ($(this) != that) {
      $(keys[this.id]).css({
        'display': 'none'
      });
      $(this).removeAttr("REQUIRED")
    }
  }) //end each
  $(keys[this.id]).css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
  $(this).attr({
    "REQUIRED": true
  })
}).trigger('init-post-format');
```

```css
#private-box,
#public-box {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-top">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="btn btn-warning">
<input type="radio" name="acc-type" value="private_office" id="private_office"> Private Office
</label>

    <label class="btn btn-warning">
<input type="radio" name="acc-type" value="public_office" id="public_office"> Public Office
</label>

  </div>


  <div id="private-box">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">Ministry</label>
      <input type="text" id="ministry" name="ministry" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">Agency </label>
      <input type="text" id="agency" name="agency" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="public-box">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">State/ Region</label>
      <input type="text" id="ministry_region" name="ministry_region" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ministry">District</label>
      <input type="text" id="ministry_district" name="ministry_district" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your support but I have still not gotten what i want. The radios are working good but there is no REQUIRED attribute added the the input fields of the ACTIVE RADIO DIV.

Comment: Yes..use you inspector tool in your browser you will see it has an attribute named required

Comment: Then how come form is still submitted whiles required input fields are empty?...Maybe there is something wrong somewhere.